# Can you change the order of Firefox plugins in the status bar?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I have several plugins that register icons in the Firefox status bar.  I would like to change the order so that plugins that pop up status changes are further to the right.  This would prevent the popups from covering up browsing real estate.  I could move other plugins (like Firebug and Y Slow) to the left which do not pop up.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I think what you speak about are *extensions*, not *plug-ins*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Firefox add-on [**Organize Status Bar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1759) will help you reorganising the items displayed in the status bar.

> OSB will enable you to organize your
>   status bar icons. You can now
>   rearrange or hide any item (icon or
>   text) in the status bar. If your
>   status bar is full and cluttered like
>   mine was, give this a try.

Comment: Lol - a plug-in to organize plug-ins!